# Unable to fully center 3 columns inside a fluid container in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, containers, col

I'm attempting to **center 3 columns** with an **offset of 1** in each insisde a **fluid container**, but for some reason all 3 colums are aligned more left than right.

Also when I resize the window all 3 columns move all the way left instead of staying centered.

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16895/

**My Questions is:**

> What is the best way to center everything: images, headings, text, and
>   columns in Bootstrap? **Note:** I want to keep all items centered no matter the screen width.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid conle">

        <row>


        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1 workscol">

        <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height =100px; alt="">
        <h2>Everything</h2>

        <p class="text-muted textworks">Sign up and shut up or i will pick a 10 pound dumbell
        and makes you got fetch it. Thank you for your patience. Have a treat</p>     

        </div>



       <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1 workscol">

           <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height =100px; alt="">
        <h2>Control Nothing</h2>
        <p class="text-muted textworks">Sign up and shut up or i will pick a 10 pound dumbell
        and makes you got fetch it. Thank you for your patience. Have a treat</p>    


        </div>


         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1 workscol">

          <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height =100px; alt="">
        <h2>Go Away</h2>
        <p class="text-muted textworks">Sign up and shut up or i will pick a 10 pound dumbell
        and makes you got fetch it. Thank you for your patience. Have a treat</p>    

        </div>
</row>
            </div> <div class="clear"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.workscol {max-width:345px;  }

.textworks {font-size:20px; }
```

Keep in mind I'm fairly new to bootstrap, but following a tutorial the above code is the best I can do. So please make sure to explain what I"m doing wrong. Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgqMWK

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fl

    uid conle">
      <row>

      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1">
        <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height =100px; alt="">
        <h2>Everything</h2>
        <p class="text-muted textworks">Sign up and shut up or i will pick a 10 pound dumbell and make you go fetch it. Thank you for your patience. Have a treat,</p>     
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-8">
        <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height =100px; alt="">
        <h2>Everything</h2>
        <p class="text-muted textworks">Sign up and shut up or i will pick a 10 pound dumbell and make you go fetch it. Thank you for your patience. Have a treat,</p>     
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-8">
        <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height =100px; alt="">
        <h2>Everything</h2>
        <p class="text-muted textworks">Sign up and shut up or i will pick a 10 pound dumbell and make you go fetch it. Thank you for your patience. Have a treat,</p>     
      </div>
     </row>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.textworks {font-size:20px; }
.conle {text-align:center; }
```

Is there a reason why you need to specify a max-width?

Comment: That's partially the answer, but the columns are not fully centered in your code. The columns are poistioned more left insted of being completely centered on the page.

Comment: "I'm attempting to center 3 columns with an offset of 1 in each inside a fluid container" -- That is why they are not completely centered.. If you wish them to be entirely center in each container, then you need to remove the offsets, i.e. `col-md-offset-1` and `col-sm-offset-1`. Or, if you wish to centralize the three sections in the entire page, while still maintaining the offsets within each section, you will need to create a container.

Comment: Also, if you were to remove the offsets entirely, you may wish to change the classes to `col-md-4` and `col-sm-4` respectively (since there are to be 3 sections and bootstrap uses a 12 column grid rule).

Comment: The max-width is actually used to keep the text paragraphs short. How do I centter it then? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrEXyG

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!